# How do you do autopostback feature of webforms in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple webgrid which displays list. I also have a combobox which contains few items. I want that when user changes the selection, the changed value should be posted to the server. How can I do this?

Any code snippets would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto-postback in Web Forms was accomplished with some JavaScript. This is not out-of-the-box in MVC, but simple enough to do on your own.

Assuming you have jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someCheckBox').change(function() {
        $('#yourFormId').submit();
    });
});
```

This is "closest" to how classic Web-Forms work; basically does "When a checkbox with the ID of 'someCheckBox' is checked or unchecked, submit the form with id 'yourFormId'. You can of course change this to your needs.

This wasn't included out-of-the-box due to most developers favoring AJAX calls instead of full-blown post-backs, which I would encourage you to do if possible. What might be more preferable is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someCheckBox').change(function() {
        $.ajax(/*make an AJAX call*/);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You implement it with ajax actions and javascript
You can find a example [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx)