# Notifications when a drop-down changes on a view in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My MVC application has drop-down in a view and I would like to know how to notify the controller when the drop-down has changed?

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Edit"))
    {
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Select an Item</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

Many Thanks
Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autopost back in mvc drop down list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729171/autopost-back-in-mvc-drop-down-list)

Comment: I see its already been answered well, so all i'll add is that many third party jquery controls exist with many events you can subscribe to. E.g. Telerik UI

Answer (score 1):

You can basically listen to the `click` event on the anchor tag items.If you want to submit the form with this value, have a hidden input in the form and set the value of that to the selected item text.

Simply add a css class to the items which we can use for wiring up the click event handler.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Edit"))
{
   <input type="hidden" id="item" name="item" value="" />
   <div class="btn-group">
     <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" 
                                                  data-toggle="dropdown">Select an Item</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="myItem">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="myItem">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="myItem">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul> 
   </div>
}
```

Now the JavaScript, get the selected item text, set it to the hidden input field and submit the form.

```
$(function() {

        $(".myItem").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
               var selectedItemText = $(this).text();
               $("#item").val(selectedItemText);
               $(this).closest("form").submit(); 
               // do whatever you want with this value. May be submit the form.
            });

});
```

Assuming your SubmitForm method has a parameter called item

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submitform(string item)
{
  // to do : Return something
}
```

If you want to send something other than the text of the item, keep it in html 5 data attribute and read it using `data()` method